# Tkinter checkbutton.select() not working on Checkbutton (Python 3)

Tags: python, checkbox, widget, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am writing a program which reads data form a file,  and adjust the settings accordingly. This is how I created the checkbutton:

```
should_auto = BooleanVar()    
autodetect = Checkbutton(root, text="Autodetect", var=should_auto, onvalue = True, offvalue = False, command=toggle_delay)
autodetect.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=7, pady=5, sticky=W)
```

I then try to "check" it using:

```
autodetect.select()
```

but this returns following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CedBook\Documents\GitHub\live-image-desktop-background\src\GUI.py", line 110, in <module>
    autodetect.select()
AttributeError: 'Checkbutton' object has no attribute 'select'
```

I have already also tried using `autodetect.set(True)`, but then i get almost the same error, but `Checkbutton object has no attribute 'set'` I saw .select() on effbot.org, but maybe that is not for python 3?

Comment: use `autodetect.set(1)`?

Comment: still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you set the value of the boolean instead?

```
should_auto.set(True)
```

should update the checkbox that relies on it.

Comment: yup that would do it..you beat me to it ;)

Comment: autodtect.set(1) might have worked, but that was the button, not the variable. Thanks anyway both of you.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Checkbutton' object has no attribute 'set'

Comment: @Ath.Bar. it sounds like you're trying to set the value of the checkbutton not the variable backing it, See the OP where `should_auto` is a `BooleanVar` and is passed to the `Checkbutton` as the `var` keyword.